# avoid force unwrapping inside a sort closure in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to sort an array of objects, based on a property which is optional Int.

```
// sorting each language array based on most stars
groupedDictionariesValueUnwrapped.sort(by: { $0.stars! > $1.stars!  })
```

Type of the array is [SingleRepository], and SingleRepository has an optional Int. stars: Int?

How should I avoid force unwrapping inside the sort?

Comment: If the property is `nil`, where should they be in the sorted list?

Comment: Consider to make the property non-optional.

Comment: yes. as you can see I am mutating the groupedDictionariesValueUnwrapped, rather than getting a new array. and nothing should be removed from it.

Comment: @vadian not possible as it has to remain optional.

Comment: Values that are `nil` could be placed at the end of the array or at the beginning? Where do you prefer them to be?

Comment: consider a default value that makes sense to your implementation

Comment: they can be placed at the end. as if the value is nil can't be compared, but should not be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sorting in descending order.

Use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to safely unwrap the values and replace `nil` with `Int.min` to place the items at the end of the array:

```
// sorting each language array based on most stars
groupedDictionariesValueUnwrapped.sort(by: { ($0.stars ?? Int.min) > ($1.stars ?? Int.min) })
```

or use `?? Int.max` to put them at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

If it makes sense for your class/struct, you can add conformance to `Comparable` to the type you want to sort:

```
extension MyClass: Comparable {
    public static func ==(lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.stars ?? 0) == (rhs.stars ?? 0)
    }

    public static func <(lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.stars ?? 0) < (rhs.stars ?? 0)
    }
}
```

You'd then be able to directly use the `>` operator function (conforming to `Comparable` brings up all other comparison operators `>`, `>=`, `<=`):

```
groupedDictionariesValueUnwrapped.sort(by: >)
```

By "making sense" I'm referring to the fact that conforming to `Comparable` based on the `stars` property adds value to the type definition (e.g. the type is named `Rating` and holds information about a user review).

Comment: It does make sense for my type to conform to Comparable, I tried your solution and encountered couple of issues. #1: I think you have mistyped the operator when you call the function. #2: when I try to call the sort like you did I get an error "Argument passed to call that take no arguments".

Comment: @Ali_C it could be the code has some flaws, I wrote it in the SO editor as I didn't had access to Xcode at that time, will revisit it and update the answer, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Ali_C fixed the function call, there was a missing `by:`. Regarding the operator, `>` is the correct one based on the code from your question (`>` automatically becomes available after implementing `Comparable`).

Comment: wow, It's pretty amazing. I didn't know the other operator becomes available automatically. Perfect working solution.